# fontawesome doesnt show the icons in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

My fontawesome in my laravel project always displays the wrong icons / bugged icons 
but i linked the most recent version.
Header contains this:

but it looks like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNKxa.png)

Answer (score 0):

sorry, something didnt work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/fontawesome.min.css"
    integrity="sha256-CuUPKpitgFmSNQuPDL5cEfPOOJT/+bwUlhfumDJ9CI4=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```